# Como retornar valor a um DateTimePicker? C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datepicker

Estou querendo retornar dados de um `DataGridView` para um `DataTimePicker` para que eu possa fazer a alteração deste dado e salva-lo novamente, mas estou com uma dificuldade em fazer isso pois o `DataTimePicker` não aceita tipo value.

```
private void btnAlterar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FrmCadCliente frmcadcliente = new FrmCadCliente();
    frmcadcliente.Show();

    frmcadcliente.txtID.Text = pacientes_TCCDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    frmcadcliente.txtNome.Text = pacientes_TCCDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    frmcadcliente.txtCPF.Text = pacientes_TCCDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    frmcadcliente.txtRG.Text = pacientes_TCCDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    frmcadcliente.cbxSexo.Text = pacientes_TCCDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
    frmcadcliente.dtpData.Text = pacientes_TCCDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
}
```

O erro acontece nesta ultima linha em `Value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode tentar fazer o seguinte:

```
frmcadcliente.dtpData.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(pacientes_TCCDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: NOSSA! muito obrigado por responder, olha deu certo sim!! eu só mudei
`frmcadcliente.dtpData.Text` para `frmcadcliente.dtpData.Value` e funcionou perfeitamente muito obrigado!

Comment: @GabrielArruda, Disponha!